# opening 2 files and adding values python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to program, which opens Two Files A.txt and B.txt, in file A there are sentences like: three litres of milk, in B file there are value to words like three 2, litres 3, of 1, milk 4
i want to open the first file and check the words values and add those values and print if the value add ups to 5. so far i have done like this :

```
count=0
with open('shopping.txt') as s: 
     with open('syllables.txt') as f:
      words = {}
      syllables = {}
      for line in f:
        word, syla = line.split()
        words[word] = syla
        syllables[syla] = word
     for lines in s:
       lines=lines.strip()
       lines=lines.split()
       for i in lines:
         lines=words[i]
         print(lines)
```

I am getting values of the words but 1 value at one line and the other in next lines.

File A contains:

```
three litres of milk
colour fast shampoo
```

File B contains:

```
sam 2
apple 3
three 2
litres 1
of 1
milk 1
colour 3
fast 1
shampoo 4
```

I want to print the line whose value totals 5 , like here the first line totals 5

Comment: Please fix indentation, some lines are indented by 4 spaces, others by 1 or 2 ...

Comment: Please post the expected output and content of fileA, fileB in proper format.

Comment: @HasnainAli you didn't actually ask a question. Also, it's still not correct indentation.

Comment: Why do you change `lines` at the end? (`lines=words[i]`). Don't you mean to write `count += words[i]`  ?

Comment: indentation should be exactly the same like in your python file

Comment: it is the same as in my python file

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary yes thank you that what files contains , can you help plz

Comment: @HasnainAli Check out my solution.

Comment: @HasnainAli For next please make sure you add things like errors, expected output and most importantly properly format your code.(That's why your question got down-voted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('A.txt') as f1, open('B.txt') as f2:
   #create a dict from fileB and don't forget to convert the count to an integer
   dic = {word : int(val)  for word, val in (line.split() for line in f2)}
   #now iterate over each line in fileA
   for line in f1:
      words = line.split()
      #get the count using `sum()`
      #dict.get would return 0 if key is not found in dic
      count = sum(dic.get(word, 0) for word in words)
      if count == 5:
         print (line, end='')  #or `print (line.strip())`
```

**output:**

```
three litres of milk
```

Notes:

1 . `str.split()` takes care of the white-spaces so there's no need of `str.strip()`.

2 . In py3.x and py2.7+ there's no need to nest `with` statements.

The above dict-comprehension is roughly equivalent to:

```
dic = {}
for line in f2:
    word, val  = line.split()
    dic[word] = int(val)
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much . i understood now how to sum up the values :)

Comment: but i did not understand the Dic{} you used. how did you do that and what does it do,? as i m very begginer :)

Comment: @HasnainAli `dic` contains the count of items fetched from `fileB`, then this `dic` is used to find the total count on each line of fileA.